# Traefik-ingress dashboard return 404

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I deploy `traefik ingress controller` pod and then two services, one of them a `LoadBalancer` type for reverse-proxy and the other a `ClusterIP` for dashboard.

Also I create ingress for redirect all `<elb-address>/dashboard` to my traefik dashboard.

but for some reason I get 404 error code when I trying to request my dashboard at `aws-ip/dashboard`

That is the manifest yamls that I use to set up traefik

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
 name: traefik-ingress-controller
 namespace: kube-system
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: traefik
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: admin
          containerPort: 8080
        args:
        - --api
        - --kubernetes
        - --logLevel=INFO
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
      port: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: traefik-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: web
```

---

Update

I am watching the log and get a the follow errors with rbac activated and the ClusterRole, ServiceRole and ServiceAccount created:

```
E1124 18:56:23.267560       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress" cannot list endpoints in the namespace "default"
E1124 18:56:23.648207       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress" cannot list services in the namespace "default"
E1124 18:56:23.267560       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress" cannot list endpoints in the namespace "default"
```

This are my serviceAccount, clusterRole and RoleBingind

```
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - pods
      - services
      - endpoints
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: traefik-ingress
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: traefik-ingress
  namespace: default
```

Comment: Which version of Traefik do you use ?

Comment: @Nepomucen traefik 1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution

I apply this

```
kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'
```

and then installed the stable/traefik template with helm

```
helm install stable/traefik --name=traefik-ingress-controller --values values.yaml
```

`values.yaml` file is:

```
    dashboard:
      enabled: true
      domain: traefik-ui.k8s.io
    rbac:
      enabled: true
    kubernetes:
      namespaces:
        - default
        - kube-system
```

Thanks for help

Comment: THANK YOU!  This just finally resolved an issue I had been having.  I suspect the real issue was the fact that I did not have rbac.enabled=true in my helm install command.   My forehead hurts from hitting against the desk!

Comment: I'm glad that help to someone :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried this myself. So basically when you create your Ingress it gets created with a `host` of `traefik-ui.minikube` (default), so you won't be able to access the dashboard with `<elb-address>/dashboard/`.

You will have to access it with `traefik-ui.minikube/dashboard/`. As an example:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get ingress
NAME              HOSTS                 ADDRESS                  PORTS   AGE
traefik-ingress   *                                                                                              80      8m13s
traefik-web-ui    traefik-ui.minikube   xxxx.elb.amazonaws.com   80      71d

$ curl -H 'Host: traefik-ui.minikube' xxxx.elb.amazonaws.com/dashboard/
<!doctype html><html class="has-navbar-fixed-top">
...
</html>
```

You can also add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file if you'd like to see it on your browser.

```
 <one-of-the-ips-of-your-elb> traefik-ui.minikube
```

And you can also use the `host` to the `rules` in your Ingress definition:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: traefik-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: yourown.hostname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: web
```

Comment: still get 404 when I hit `http://<accountid>.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com/dashboard/`

Comment: I apply that configuration, but still get 404...

And when execute `kubectl get ingress -n kube-system` the address column is empty :S

Comment: I suppose that resolve to my LoadBalancer service of traefik

Comment: Update my question

Answer (score 2):

Just because I ran into this, the [docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/dashboard/) say:

> The trailing slash / in /dashboard/ is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem this week.
I tried many solutions, but the simplest one worked.
Try /#/ after /dashboard.