# Traefik dashboard/web UI 404 when installed via helm on Digitalocean single node cluster

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-helm, traefik-ingress

I am trying to set Traefik as my ingress controller and load balancer on a single node cluster(Digital Ocean). Following [the official Traefik setup guide](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/user-guide/kubernetes.md#deploy-traefik-using-helm-chart) I installed Traefik using helm:

```
helm install --values values.yaml stable/traefik

# values.yaml
dashboard:
 enabled: true
 domain: traefik-ui.minikube
kubernetes:
 namespaces:
  - default
  - kube-system

#output
RESOURCES:
==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                                  READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
operatic-emu-traefik-f5dbf4b8f-z9bzp  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         1s

==> v1/ConfigMap

NAME                  AGE
operatic-emu-traefik  1s

==> v1/Service
operatic-emu-traefik-dashboard  1s
operatic-emu-traefik            1s

==> v1/Deployment
operatic-emu-traefik  1s

==> v1beta1/Ingress
operatic-emu-traefik-dashboard  1s
```

Then I created the service exposing the Web UI
`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/master/examples/k8s/ui.yaml`

Then I can clearly see my traefik pod running and an external-ip being assigned:

```
NAME                                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
service/dashboard                        ClusterIP      10.245.156.214   <none>           443/TCP                      11d
service/kubernetes                       ClusterIP      10.245.0.1       <none>           443/TCP                      14d
service/operatic-emu-traefik             LoadBalancer   10.245.137.41    <external-ip>   80:31190/TCP,443:30207/TCP   5m7s
service/operatic-emu-traefik-dashboard   ClusterIP      10.245.8.156     <none>           80/TCP                       5m7s
```

Then opening http://external-ip/dashboard/ leads to 404 page not found

I read a ton of answers and tutorials but keep missing something. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I am writing this post as the information is a bit much to fit in a comment. After spending enough time on understanding how k8s and helm charts work, this is how I solved it:

Firstly, I missed the RBAC part, I did not create ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding in order to authorise Traefik to use K8S API (as I am using 1.12 version). Hence, either I should have deployed ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding manually or added the following in my `values.yaml`

```
rbac:
  enabled: true
```

Secondly, I tried to access dashboard ui from ip directly without realising Traefik uses hostname to direct to its dashboard as @Rico mentioned above (I am voting you up as you did provide helpful info but I did not manage to connect all pieces of the puzzle at that time). So, either edit your `/etc/hosts` file linking your hostname to the `external-ip` and then access the dashboard via browser or test that it is working with curl:

```
curl http://external-ip/dashboard/ -H 'Host: traefik-ui.minikube'
```

To sum up, you should be able to install Traefik and access its dashboard ui by installing:

```
helm install --values values.yaml stable/traefik
# values.yaml
dashboard:
  enabled: true
  domain: traefik-ui.minikube
rbac:
  enabled: true
kubernetes:
  namespaces:
   - default
   - kube-system
```

and then editing your hosts file and opening the hostname you chose.

Now the confusing part from the [official traefik setup guide](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/user-guide/kubernetes.md#deploy-traefik-using-helm-chart) is the section named `Submitting an Ingress to the Cluster` just below the `Deploy Traefik using Helm Chart` that instructs to install a service and an ingress object in order to be able to access the dashboard. This is unneeded as the official stable/traefik helm chart provides both of them. You would need that if you want to install traefik by deploying all needed objects manually. However for a person just starting out with k8s and helm, it looks like that section needs to be completed after installing helm via the official stable/traefik chart.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53403956/2989261).

You either have to connect with the `traefik-ui.minikube` hostname or add a `host` entry on your Ingress definition like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: traefik-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: yourown.hostname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: web
```

You can check with:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get ingress
```

Comment: I have host entry in the ingress definition, it does not work though. `kubectl -n kube-system get ingress` outputs empty address. Maybe that is what is missing. How can I set that?